# In foldl, are these the actual numbers or just placeholders for the numbers?

Tags: haskell

I have a question about this nice article:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'

When they reach this step in the `foldl` example:

```
let z1 =  0 + 1
    z2 = z1 + 2
    z3 = z2 + 3
    z4 = z3 + 4
    ...
    z999997 = z999996 + 999997
    z999998 = z999997 + 999998
    z999999 = z999998 + 999999
    z1000000 = z999999 + 1000000
in z1000000
```

Are those mentions of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `999999`, and `1000000` actually the numbers themselves, or are they really just placeholders for those numbers -- placeholders that aren't replaced with the actual numbers until later in the computation (when they are actually needed for performing the actual additions)?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: tricky question ;) ... to understand the article you can assume them to be the actual numbers (not thunks)

Comment: @Carsten Actually, I think that such example is meant to show how `foldl` will always build large thunks, so it's better to regard the `z1,...` values as "placeholders"/unevaluated expressions/thunks. Section 3 then shows that `foldl'` forces those thunks at every step, preventing them from wasting memory.

Comment: @chi maybe I was not clear enough - but that was what I meant - I thought haskellHQ was asking if the numbers there where some kind of thunk too (and if you want to be nasty you could say that they are `fromInteger 999997` or something close) - and I just wanted to point out that for the sake of this article it's a good idea to tread them as fully evaluated numbers and concentrate on the other parts

Comment: Ah, the question is about the _numbers_, i.e. the numerical constants, not the `z1,...` values. I missed that. Yes, in that case I agree that it's best to regard them as evaluated numbers for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the point of that discussion is completely independent of this detail, so, *as far as that discussion goes* you can treat them as fully evaluated.

Secondly that "step by step" description they give is *not* a formally defined reduction that's guaranteed to happen exactly as written. They are only giving the *idea* of what would happen in that case, so nitpicking about that is quite useless.

Now **actually** they *could* not be fully evaluated. The `[n..m]` syntax is really syntactic sugar for a call to `enumFromTo n m`. Depending on how `enumFromTo` is evaluated those numbers may actually be things like `1`, `1+1`, `(1+1)+1` etc.

However the point they are making would hold even when doing:

```
veryBigList `deepseq` foldl (+) 0 veryBigList
```

Where `deepseq` assures you that the `veryBigList` is completely evaluated before the `foldl` takes place. The problem is that even in this case `foldl` would create a huge thunk.

Moreover the thunks representing those numbers would *probably* depend on the thunks of previous numbers, as if they were:

```
let n1 = 1
    z1 = 0 + n1
    n2 = n1 + 1
    z2 = z1 + n2
    n3 = n2 + 1
    z3 = z2 + n3
    ...
in ...
```

This means that if you solve the problem with the `zi` thunks you *automatically* fix the problem with the `ni` thunks too, since they are produced and consumed one at a time, and once you evaluate the thunk `ni` it wont be re-evaluated to compute `n(i+1)`.
This means that even those thunks would have constant size.

So, to repeat the first point, it's not something you should be worrying about when looking at that discussion.